# User registration using file upload in php

Tags: php, html, database, file-upload, registration

I am currently working on a lost and found system using php in which I have to modify the user registration approach being used in the program. What I wanted to do is to register users with the use of csv file upload and automatically register the users in the database according to the file contents. So, do you have any idea or suggestions on how could I make this approach possible?

Comment: you can use [phpspreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) read csv file and insert it to database

Comment: @BehzadGhanadi i don't know why you would recommend something so complex for just reading a CSV file. php has build in function for that

Comment: @tim yes, but that library is so useful and has lots of valuable functions if he learned it, he can use it more and more in future.

Comment: when the only tool you own is a hammer ...

Comment: CSV file must have a  specific format..i.e `row` and `columns` . if its has some specific `rows` and `columns` then  i can help i did something in the same way.

Comment: @BehzadGhanadi thank you for your suggestion, I think I could take that into consideration.

Comment: @danish-khan-I yes that is exactly what I am trying to do, what I need is to access each row and column corresponding to the user's info and directly register the content in the database after reading the file.